# Concatenate string using IF statement

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I feel like this has had to have been asked before, but I might just not know how to word to search correctly.

So, in my stored I take in some information and I want to create a `varchar` string based on this information. Lets say I have these three variables.

```
@String varchar(MAX) = '',
@BroughtInInfo bit
```

And now I have something like the following

```
SET @String = 'Here is a string and I want to add'
    IF @BroughtInInfo = 1
    BEGIN  
      +'This info'+
    END
    ELSE
      +'That info'+
'Then more stuff here after conditional statement'
```

Now, I'm getting syntax error near `+`  I've tried a lot of combinations of moving the plus signs around the conditional statement but it doesn't play nice.

I'm pretty new to SQL so any tips and tricks will help! Thanks!

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: @HABO Ah, gotcha'.  I'll keep that in mind for future SQL posts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you are looking for is `CASE` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)).

```
SET @String = 'Here is a string and I want to add' + 
    CASE WHEN @BroughtInInfo = 1 
        THEN 'This info'
        ELSE 'That info'
    END
    + 'Then more stuff here after conditional statement'
```

Comment: Works great! No wonder I was having trouble searching it! I was just looking at IF statements.  I'll accept once it lets me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try This on SQLServer 2008 it will work

> declare @String varchar(max);
>
> declare @BroughtInInfo bit;
>
> SET @String = 'Here is a string and I want to add'
>
> ```
> IF @BroughtInInfo = 1
> BEGIN  
> SET @String +='This info'
> END
> ELSE
>   SET @String +='This info'   select @String
> ```